# Can I substitute multiple items in a single regular expression in VIM or Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, vim

Let's say I have string "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog" can I change this to "The slow brown fox jumps over the energetic dog" with one regular expression?  Currently, I use two sets of regular expressions for this situation. (In this case, I use `s/quick/slow/` followed by `s/lazy/energetic/`.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The second part of a substitution is a double quoted string, so any normal interpolation can occur.  This means you can use the value of the capture to index into a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


my %replace = (
    quick => "slow",
    lazy  => "energetic",
);

my $regex = join "|", keys %replace;
$regex = qr/$regex/;

my $s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

$s =~ s/($regex)/$replace{$1}/g;

print "$s\n";
```

Comment: What does that do? evaluate the replacement? Is there something like this in other programming languages?

Comment: It doesn't need /e becuase it is a simple interpolation, try the code before making claims.

Comment: this approach will have problems if you'll ever want to have 2 replace strings that one of them is prefix of another (for example: "dep"=>1, "depesz" => 2). to avoid the problem you should sort the keys of %replace by descreasing length of key.

Answer (score 56):

You can do this in vim using a Dictionary:

```
:%s/quick\|lazy/\={'quick':'slow','lazy':'energetic'}[submatch(0)]/g
```

This will change the following text:

> The **quick** brown fox ran **quick**ly next to the **lazy** brook.

into:

> The **slow** brown fox ran **slow**ly next to the **energetic** brook.

To see how this works, see `:help sub-replace-expression` and `:help Dictionary`.  In short,

- `\=` lets you substitute in the result of a vim expression.
- `{'quick':'slow', 'lazy':'energetic'}` is a vim dictionary (like a hash in perl or ruby, or an object in javascript) that uses `[]` for lookups.
- `submatch(0)` is the matched string

This can come in handy when refactoring code - say you want to exchange the variable names for `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` changing

- `foo` → `bar`
- `bar` → `baz`
- `baz` → `foo`

Using a sequence of `%s///` commands would be tricky, unless you used temporary variable names - but you'd have to make sure those weren't hitting anything else.  Instead, you can use a Dictionary to do it in one pass:

```
:%s/\<\%(foo\|bar\|baz\)\>/\={'foo':'bar','bar':'baz','baz':'foo'}[submatch(0)]/g
```

Which changes this code

```
int foo = 0;
float bar = pow(2.0, (float) foo);
char baz[256] = {};

sprintf(baz,"2^%d = %f\n", foo, bar);
```

into:

```
int bar = 0;
float baz = pow(2.0, (float) bar);
char foo[256] = {};

sprintf(foo,"2^%d = %f\n", bar, baz);
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you may want to add the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
" Refactor the given lines using a dictionary
" replacing all occurences of each key in the dictionary with its value
function! Refactor(dict) range
  execute a:firstline . ',' . a:lastline .  's/\C\<\%(' . join(keys(a:dict),'\|'). '\)\>/\='.string(a:dict).'[submatch(0)]/ge'
endfunction

command! -range=% -nargs=1 Refactor :<line1>,<line2>call Refactor(<args>)
```

This lets you use the `:Refactor {'frog':'duck', 'duck':'frog'}` command, and is slightly 
less repetitive than creating the regex for the dict manually.

Answer (score 19):

You can concatenate vim substitutions:

The quick brown fox ran quickly next to the lazy brook.

```
:s/quick/slow/|s/lazy/energetic/
```

The slow brown fox ran quickly next to the energetic brook.

The advantage here is that you have to type your substitutions just once

Rgds

Comment: Not a single regular expression as requested by the question, but +1 for best solution to the vim portion of the problem, IMHO.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You can do the following.

```
:%s/quick\(.*\)lazy/slow\1energetic
```

The trick is to use the parens to match the text between the two words.  You can then reference this text in the substitution string by using `\1`.  You can also use `\2` for the second matched paren expression and so on.  This allows you to replace multiple words without disturbing the text inbetween.

Comment: What if there are many occurrences of quick and lazy that are interleaved?

Comment: @allyourcode, then it will replace the outermost pair. This is only slighty different than Tg's example which would replace the first occurance.

Answer (score 3):

In perl:

```
s/quick(.*)lazy/slow${1}energetic/;
```

In vim:

```
s/quick\(.*\)lazy/slow\1energetic/;
```

Answer (score 0):

Chas's answer is good, the only other thing I'd mention is that if you're doing word swaps you probably want to be matching on

\b(foo|bar|baz|qux)\b

to avoid matching substrings.  If you doing a *lot* of word swapping, you might start to find regexps a bit limiting and want to do something like:

```
join '', map { exists $subst{$_} ? $subst{$_} : $_ } split /\b/, $string
```

Answer (score -1):

There's a neat way to do it in Ruby using [gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000832) with a block:

```
s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
subs = {'quick' => 'slow', 'lazy' => 'industrious'}
s.gsub(/quick|lazy/) { |match| subs[match] }
# => "The slow brown fox jumps over the industrious dog"
```