# Vim substitution of a list of words with another same length list of words?

Tags: regex, vim, replace, substitution

I need to substitute a list of words with with an equally long list of words.

So for example you have:
"a","b","c","d","e","f"

And you want to replace each word with the uppercase version of each word:
"A","B","C","D","E","F"

I know how to find each string using the regex:
(a\|b\|c\|d\|e\|f)

I know you could do a global substitution for each word. But when the length of the words gets large this approach would become un-wieldly and inelegant.

Is there a way to somehow do one global substitution? Similar to:

```
:%s/\(a\|b\|c\|d\|e\|f\)/INSERT_REPLACEMENT_LIST/
```

I am not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, would you mind telling, what is this for ? I mean, what is it good for, in practice ? Nothing comes to mind, so I was wondering.

Comment: @Idigas, I am doing a bunch of refactoring on some bad Matlab code. I noticed that the code uses like 20-30 globals and his globals aren't all uppercase or named in such a way to make them obviously global. --> SO I would like to rename them all to be all uppercase. Or possibly the same name but add "_g" after each variable name.

Comment: @Idigas, eventually I will be implementing the Matlab in C. So I want to fully understand and make the code as elegant as possible before converting to C.

Comment: @Igor, who gave a specific solution to the example given in the question. The example I gave in the question was the simplest case scenario meant to illustrate my problem. In reality each a or b or c is a string that will be replaced by another string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a dictionary of items mapped to their replacements, then use that in the right side of the search/replace.

```
:let r={'a':'A', 'b':'B', 'c':'C', 'd':'D', 'e':'E'}
:%s/\v(a|b|c|d|e)/\=r[submatch(1)]/g
```

See `:h sub-replace-\=` and `:h submatch()`.  If you want to cram that into one line, you could use a literal dictionary.

```
:%s/\v(a|b|c|d|e)/\={'a':'A','b':'B','c':'C','d':'D','e':'E'}[submatch(1)]/g
```

The specific example you gave of uppercasing letters would be more simply done as

```
:%s/[a-e]/\U\0/g
```

Comment: s/\\(\a\+\\)/\U\0/g to change sequences of alphabetical characters to upper case.

Comment: If you find yourself doing this often, you define a vim function for this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765894/can-i-substitute-multiple-items-in-a-single-regular-expression-in-vim-or-perl/766093#766093)

Comment: @Brian, what is the "\v" in your substitution?

Comment: @Brian, when I do my substitutions I have to put a backslash to escape the '(', '|', and ')' characters. Why do you not have to? Or is your syntax wrong?

Comment: The \v puts the regex into "very magic" mode, which lets you avoid backslashes.  See :h /\v

Answer (score 3):

:%s/(a\|b\|c\|d\|e\|f)/\U\0/g