# how to write only one pattern to exchange two strings in two-ways in vim

Tags: vim

xxx <=> zzz

---

Original text:

`xxxyyyzzz`

Run command:

`:s/???/???/`

It becomes:

`zzzyyyxxx`

Run the same command above:

`:s/???/???/`

Back to the original text:

`xxxyyyzzz`

---

just like toggle case(~)

`aBCdeFg` <=> `AbcDEfG`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at this:  [Can I substitute multiple items in a single regular expression in VIM or Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765894/can-i-substitute-multiple-items-in-a-single-regular-expression-in-vim-or-perl/766093#766093)

Comment: `:s/xxx\|zzz/\={'xxx':'zzz','zzz':'xxx'}[submatch(0)]/g` is what i want. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
:s/(...)(yyy)(...)/\3\2\1/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always write your own macro.  I'm assuming a macro for this specific example would not be helpful to you, but I could post one if you want.