# Reverse order of string to find and string to replace in vim

Tags: vim, replace

I often find myself doing

```
:s/foo/bar/g
*move to different line*
:s/bar/foo/g
```

on different lines. Is there an easy way to swap them around so that I can execute the second version quickly?

Comment: Do you want to swap to strings around? The example you gave seens to do "nothing" sice "foo" will be "foo" after the replacement.

Comment: I've edited it to make it clearer. I'd like to do one find and replace somewhere and then one the reverse of it somewhere else. It happens reasonably often to me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237908/how-to-write-only-one-pattern-to-exchange-two-strings-in-two-ways-in-vim)

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Abolish](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1545) plugin ([git homepage](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish)):

```
 :Subvert/{foo,bar}/{bar,foo}/g
```

Without plugin:

```
 :%s/foo\|bar/\=submatch(0) ==# 'foo' ? 'bar' : 'foo'/g
```

Answer (score 2):

The quick use once only option is to do the following

```
:s/~/<c-r>//g<cr>
```

`~` matches the last substitution and `<c-r>/` will insert the current search string from the `"/` register. Therefore flipping the substitution. A word of warning is that `~` can only be used once because after the substitution it will be changed. Also doing a search between substitutions will result in the `"/` register changing.

As an alternative you could try to use the command-line window to edit the command like text in any other window.

Use `q:` to open the command-line window from normal mode or press <kbd>ctrl-f</kbd> from the command line (assuming the default setting for `'cedit'`).

Drew Neil has a vimcasts episode that deals with [refining search patterns via the command-window](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/) which is similar.

```
:h /~
:h c_CTRL-R
:h quote/
:h cmdwin
:h q:
:h 'cedit'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dict` in vim

```
:%s/foo\|bar/\={'foo':'bar', 'bar':'foo'}[submatch(0)]/g
```