# Vim replace two words with one another

Tags: vim, command, vi

How would one replace all instances of 'foo' with 'bar' and 'bar' with 'foo' in vim?

Comment: As you have found an answer, please mark it accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aside from using a temporary word for the change, you could also use [abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) plugin like this:

```
:%SubVert/{foo,bar}/{bar,foo}/g
```

Answer (score 13):

Take a look at this: [how to write only one pattern to exchange two strings in two-ways in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237908/how-to-write-only-one-pattern-to-exchange-two-strings-in-two-ways-in-vim)

```
:s/foo\|bar/\={'foo':'bar','bar':'foo'}[submatch(0)]/g
```

Comment: This is a little more complex, yes, but no plugin? many might prefer this.

Comment: @JasonMcGhee: When the substitute string starts with "\=" the remainder is interpreted as an expression.

Answer (score 1):

1. :%s/foo/bbaarr/g
2. :%s/bar/foo/g
3. :%s/bbaarr/foo/g

It must exist an smartest way to do it, but this one will work for sure !

Comment: Correction

3. :%s/bbaarr/bar/g

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using temp word. Just be sure that it doesn't exists in the current document.

```
/\<asd123\>
:%s/\<foo\>/asd123/g
:%s/\<asd123\>/bar/g
:%s/\<bar\>/foo/g
```