# Is it possible to abbreviate two words in vim by using the command ab

Tags: vim, command, vi, ex

My question is simple: Is there a way to abbreviate two words separated by a **space** using only the **`ab`** command in `vi`...Is it possible to escape the space character ?

In stackoverflow I found only this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273377/vim-replace-two-words-with-one-another), but all answers were using **substitution command**. I also tried:

`:ab word1<space>word2 replaceWord`

but in vain (generated an error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible.

From `:help :abbreviate` :

```
Examples of strings that cannot be abbreviations: "a.b", "#def", "a b", "_$r"
```

That is because there are only three types of abbreviations (still from `:help`) :

```
full-id   The "full-id" type consists entirely of keyword characters (letters
      and characters from 'iskeyword' option).  This is the most common
      abbreviation.

      Examples: "foo", "g3", "-1"

end-id    The "end-id" type ends in a keyword character, but all the other
      characters are not keyword characters.

      Examples: "#i", "..f", "$/7"

non-id    The "non-id" type ends in a non-keyword character, the other
      characters may be of any type, excluding space and tab.  {this type
      is not supported by Vi}

      Examples: "def#", "4/7$"
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually it can be emulated.

You'll have to define an abbreviation on `word2` that'll check what precedes it. I did detailed an [answer about having abbreviation starting with '\'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1680834/15934), it's the same (except you may have to test the last word on the preceding line).