# Python: replace named groups by dictionary

Tags: python, regex, replace, python-2.7

How can I replace `\s+` to single spance, all `;` to `,`, all `a.m` to `AM`, all `x` to `y`
I am new to named group replacement, how could I replace set of characters to the set of replacement characters using single RegEx and single sub() calling.

If I can keep all replacement strings in a dict and have a single RegEx string that could be the smart way.

```
Eg: M-Th    5:30 am-10 pm; F    5:30 a.m-10:30 p.m, Sa 10:30-10:30, Su 10:30-10 x y z x
Output: M-Th 5:30 AM-10 PM, F 5:30 AM - 10:30 PM, Sa 10:30 - 10:30, Su 10:30-10 y y z y
```

Comment: I want like this in python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765894/can-i-substitute-multiple-items-in-a-single-regular-expression-in-vim-or-perl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
 mydict = {"\s+":" ", ";":",", "a.m":"AM","x":"y"}
 mystr = "M-Th    5:30 am-10 pm; F    5:30 a.m-10:30 p.m, Sa 10:30-10:30, Su 10:30-10 x y z x"

 for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
    mystr = mystr.replace(k, v)

 print mystr
```

**OUTPUT**

```
M-Th    5:30 am-10 pm, F    5:30 AM-10:30 p.m, Sa 10:30-10:30, Su 10:30-10 y y z y
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider :-

```
import re
def sub(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group(0) == ';':
        return ':'
    elif matchobj.group(0) == 'a.m.':
        return 'AM'
    elif re.match('\\s+$', matchobj.group(0)):
        return ' '

print re.sub(';|\\s+|a.m.', sub, '10; a.m.          ;')
```

Sample run :-

```
C:\>python st.py
10:AM
```

Or perhaps ( borrowing from Ammar whose solution I liked for being concise :) :-

```
import re
mydict = {"\s+":" ", ";":",", "a.m":"AM","x":"y"}

def sub(matchobj):
    for k, v in mydict.iteritems():
        if re.match('%s$' % k, matchobj.group(0)):
            return v

print re.sub('|'.join(mydict.keys()), sub, 'M-Th    5:30 am-10 pm; F    5:30 a.m-10:30 p.m, Sa 10:30-10:30, Su 10:30-10 x y z x')
```

Which works as well :-

```
C:\>python st.py
M-Th 5:30 am-10 pm, F 5:30 AM-10:30 p.m, Sa 10:30-10:30, Su 10:30-10 y y
```