# change words for others in a list of equivalents without losing format

Tags: regex, perl

having a input folder,
and output folder 
and a list of equivalents folder.

where can i start to research, in order to if i have a word in a list document inside input folder, get it's equivalent from the list of equivalents, and make the replacement and produce a txt output, always using utf8 in all documents.

if i have a list of equivalents:

```
bovine = cattle
cancrine = crab
canine = dog
cervine = deer
corvine = crow
equine = horse
elapine = snake
```

and i have a input document like this:

```
bovine cancrine canine cervine equine text1 text2 elapine.
```

i want it to be like this in the output file:

```
cattle crab dog deer [text1] [text2] snake
```

text1 and text2 are in square brackets since they are not in the list of equivalents.

but to be able of changing the word even if is followed by a coma or other punctuation marks.
so for example and input like this:

```
bovine! cancrine, ,canine# cervine% $equine text1, text2,,, elapine......
```

should return:

```
cattle! crab, ,dog# deer% $horse [text1], [text2[,,, snake......
```

using a perl script, please.
i should say i am not a programmer, but one friend of mine made a program like that for me years ago, it was just a couple of lines, but that is what i understood.
i just remember he was using a regex: `^[^=]+=[.*]+$`  to read the equivalents something like that.

i am using active perl, last version.
and i want to include in the equivalents the caracters °ŸÖ†ª  Or maybe other ascii character, i can't contact my friend anymore, so i am asking help for doing this, to translate english words into phonetics.
thanks

it is suppoused that the script should be on the same folder, that cointains the 3 folders, input, output and list.
so if i double click on the script, the input text should be converted and placed a file in the output folder.

thanks for the help

Comment: You can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765894/can-i-substitute-multiple-items-in-a-single-regular-expression-in-vim-or-perl

Comment: what happens is that i have already a list of equivalents more than 200 hundred thousands.  so the input text can vary to much. so that is why the need of big list of equivalents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with `perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $LOOKUP , "<" , "file.txt";
open my $LIST   , "<" , "list.txt";
open my $OUTPUT , ">" , "output.txt";

my %h;

while (<$LOOKUP>) {
    chomp;
    my ($k, $v) = split /\s*=\s*/;
    $h{$k} = $v;
}

while (<$LIST>) {
    s/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$h{$1} || "[$1]"/eg;
    print $OUTPUT $_;
}
```

#### For fun a one-liner:

```
perl -lpe '
BEGIN{$x=pop;%h=map{$_->[0]=>$_->[2]}map[split],<>;@ARGV=$x}
s/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$h{$1}||"[$1]"/eg' file.txt list.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: i see it now! thanks again, your script is smaller than the one my friend did, and still works. =)